# Proper power supply for BLDC motor

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor, high-current

I'm not entirely sure how to choose power supply for bldc motor. I have 2 80wat motors with controller (black box, i cant find out what inside), but stall current for both of them can be close to 80A. Controller has 3 wires conected directly to motor. Can I buy simple power supply for 24V and install in series diode for 80A like in this article https://www.heliosps.com/dc-power-supplies-dc-motors/? This would be enought for protecting from damage and also make proper condition for this motors? Or maybe use additional shunt regulator?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

80W motor with current of 40A and supply of 24V? Makes no sense at first look, but this 40A stall current is measured at speed = 0 (rotor locked), this is not a working range of the motor

Your driver works as buck converter, so you don't need 2 x 40A x 24V supply power.  You should use the nominal current of the motor, not the stall current for proper supply calculation, the short term high current can be supplied by a capacitor bank. Look also for max. peak motor current, not a stall current.

Comment: Datasheet provide nominal and stall currnet. Also do I need special power supply for that? Maybe can you suggest specific product? What about protection?

Comment: You didn't provide any data about motor and driver, only a useless 3rd party link.

Comment: Driver is EPOS4 50/15 from maxon and motor is EC-i 30 and EC-i 40 from maxon also

Comment: @Toriam Sum the two noninal currents, add some reserve and you get it. I guess somewhere in the range of 5A.

Comment: Do i need additional protection? Like a diode in series?